# How to set id and value for jcombobox when fetching id and value from database

Tags: java, swing

When I fetch `category_id` and `category_name` from `database` and I want to set that value to `JComboBox` like `cat_id` as index and `cat_name` as item using `swing`.

```
public DefaultComboBoxModel getCategoryItems()
{
    con=ConnectionClass.getConnection();
    DefaultComboBoxModel categoryItems = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement getCatStmt=con.prepareStatement("select    cat_id,cat_name from category", ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,   ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE);
        ResultSet catRS=getCatStmt.executeQuery();
        while (catRS.next()) {
            categoryItems.addElement(catRS.getString("cat_name"));
            //Here, I want to set index id  and value
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CategoryDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null, ex);
        }
    }
    return categoryItems;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you format your code please?..

Comment: Hello sir,can you please check this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create another class (say Category) to hold both the cat_id and cat_name. Something as follows:

```
class Category {
   int id ;
   String name ;

   public String toString() {
      return name ;
   }
}
```

Add a new Category with the id and name from the result set. When the item is selected, the selection will be a Category object from which the cat_id can be retrieved. Remember to override toString() - because this is what the ComboBox displays.

Comment: Happy that it helped. I don't know about the etiquette on SO, but IMO, if a answer helps you in solving the issue - you should accept that answer. The answers are supposed to provide you a direction, not full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Item
    {
        private int id;
        private String description;

        public Item(int id, String description)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return description;
        }
    }      


public DefaultComboBoxModel getCategoryItems()
       {
       con=ConnectionClass.getConnection();
       DefaultComboBoxModel categoryItems = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
       try
       {PreparedStatement getCatStmt=con.prepareStatement("select  cat_id,cat_name from category ", ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE);
       ResultSet catRS=getCatStmt.executeQuery();
       while (catRS.next()) {
       categoryItems.addElement( new com.hotel.bean.Item(catRS.getInt("cat_id"), catRS.getString("cat_name") ) );
        }
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(CategoryDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            return categoryItems;

        }
```